# Create pencil-like body in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to create this object using WEBGL

[image]

I am a beginner in WEBGL. I want to use those code I have made to finish the shape. I have created two objects so far: cone, and cylinder. This is my code for both cone, and cylinder.

```
function Cone(resolution){
        this.name = "cone";
        this.vertices = new Float32Array(3*(resolution+2));

        this.vertices[0] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[1] = 2.0;
        this.vertices[2] = 0.0;

        var radius = 1.0;
        var angle;
        var step = 6.283185307179586476925286766559 / resolution;

        var vertexoffset = 3;

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            angle = step*i;
            this.vertices[vertexoffset] = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            this.vertices[vertexoffset+1] = 0.0;
            this.vertices[vertexoffset+2] = radius * Math.sin(angle);
            vertexoffset +=3;
        }

        this.vertices[vertexoffset] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[vertexoffset+1] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;

        this.triangleIndices = new Uint16Array(3*2*resolution);

        var triangleoffset = 0;

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = 0;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = 1 + (i % resolution);
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] = 1 + ((i+1) % resolution);
            triangleoffset +=3;
        }

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = resolution + 1;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = 1 + (i % resolution);
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] =((i+1) % resolution); 
            triangleoffset +=3;
        }

        this.numVertices = this.vertices.length/3;
        this.numTriangles = this.triangleIndices.length/3;
}

function Cylinder(resolution){
        this.name = "cylinder";
        this.vertices = new Float32Array(3*(2*resolution+2));

        this.vertices[0] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[1] = 2.0;
        this.vertices[2] = 0.0;

        var radius = 1.0;
        var angle;
        var step = 6.283185307179586476925286766559 / resolution;

        var vertexoffset = 0;

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){

            angle = step*i;

            this.vertices[vertexoffset] = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            this.vertices[vertexoffset+1] = 0.0;
            this.vertices[vertexoffset+2] = radius * Math.sin(angle);

            vertexoffset +=3;
        }

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){

            angle = step*i;

            this.vertices[vertexoffset] = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            this.vertices[vertexoffset+1] = 2.0;
            this.vertices[vertexoffset+2] = radius * Math.sin(angle);

            vertexoffset +=3;
        }

        this.vertices[vertexoffset] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[vertexoffset+1] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;

        vertexoffset +=3;

        this.vertices[vertexoffset] = 0.0;
        this.vertices[vertexoffset+1] = 2.0;
        this.vertices[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;



        this.triangleIndices = new Uint16Array(3*4*resolution);

        var triangleoffset = 0;

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = i;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = (i+1) % resolution;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] = (i % resolution) + resolution;
            triangleoffset +=3;


            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = (i % resolution) + resolution;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = (i+1) % resolution;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] = ((i+1) % resolution) + resolution;
            triangleoffset +=3;
        }

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = i;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = ((i+1) % resolution);
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] =2*resolution; 
            triangleoffset +=3;
        }

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = resolution + i;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = ((i+1) % resolution) + 
    resolution;
            this.triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] =2*resolution +1; 
            triangleoffset +=3;
        }

        this.numVertices = this.vertices.length/3;
        this.numTriangles = this.triangleIndices.length/3;
}
```

I want to use these codes and combine them to complete the body!

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: @ljᛃ I have wrote the question before and also after the code. go and check it

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cylinder with (the top and bottom disc), then you have only the change the height of the center point of one of the disc to get the result what you want.

```
this.vertices[0] = 0.0;
this.vertices[1] = 4.0; // Change this from 2.0 to e.g 4.0
this.vertices[2] = 0.0;
```

See the example:

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls;

function CylinderGeometry(radius, holeRadius, height, segments, openEnded) {
    THREE.Geometry.call(this);
    this.type = 'CylinderGeometry';
    this.fromBufferGeometry(new CylinderBufferGeometry(radius, holeRadius, height, segments, openEnded));
    this.mergeVertices();
}

CylinderGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Geometry.prototype);
CylinderGeometry.prototype.constructor = CylinderGeometry;

function CylinderBufferGeometry(radius, holeRadius, height, segments, openEnded) {

    THREE.BufferGeometry.call(this);
    this.type = 'CylinderBufferGeometry';
    var scope = this;

    // buffers

    var indices = [];
    var vertices = [];
    var normals = [];
    var uvs = [];

    Cylinder(20.0);

    this.setIndex(indices);
    this.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    this.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(normals, 3));
    this.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));

    function Cylinder(resolution) {

        var radius = 1.0;
        var angle;
        var step = 6.283185307179586476925286766559 / resolution;

        var h0 = -1;
        var h1 = 0.5;
        var h2 = 2.0;

        var vertexoffset = 0;
        var uvOffset = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){

            angle = step*i;

            vertices[vertexoffset] = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            vertices[vertexoffset+1] = h0;
            vertices[vertexoffset+2] = radius * Math.sin(angle);

            normals[vertexoffset] = Math.cos(angle);
            normals[vertexoffset+1] = h0;
            normals[vertexoffset+2] = Math.sin(angle);

            uvs[uvOffset] = i/resolution
            uvs[uvOffset+1] = 2.0;

            vertexoffset +=3;
            uvOffset += 2;
        }

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){

            angle = step * i;

            vertices[vertexoffset] = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            vertices[vertexoffset+1] = h1;
            vertices[vertexoffset+2] = radius * Math.sin(angle);

            normals[vertexoffset] = Math.cos(angle)
            normals[vertexoffset+1] = h1;
            normals[vertexoffset+2] = Math.sin(angle);

            uvs[uvOffset] = i/resolution
            uvs[uvOffset+1] = 2.0;

            vertexoffset +=3;
            uvOffset += 2;
        }

        vertices[vertexoffset] = 0.0;
        vertices[vertexoffset+1] = h0;
        vertices[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;
        normals[vertexoffset] = 0.0
        normals[vertexoffset+1] = -1.0;
        normals[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;
        uvs[uvOffset] = 0.5
        uvs[uvOffset+1] = 0.5;

        vertexoffset +=3;

        vertices[vertexoffset] = 0.0;
        vertices[vertexoffset+1] = h2;
        vertices[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;
        normals[vertexoffset] = 0.0
        normals[vertexoffset+1] = 1.0;
        normals[vertexoffset+2] = 0.0;
        uvs[uvOffset] = 0.0
        uvs[uvOffset+1] = 1.0;

        var groupOffset = 0;
        var groupCount = 0;
        var triangleoffset = 0;
        var triangleIndices = indices;
        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = i;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] = (i+1) % resolution;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = (i % resolution) + resolution;
            triangleoffset +=3;
            groupCount += 3;

            triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = (i % resolution) + resolution;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] = (i+1) % resolution;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = ((i+1) % resolution) + resolution;
            triangleoffset +=3;
            groupCount += 3;
        }

        scope.addGroup(groupOffset, groupCount-groupOffset, 0);
        groupOffset = groupCount;

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = i;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] = ((i+1) % resolution);
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] =2*resolution; 
            triangleoffset +=3;
            groupCount += 3;
        }

        for(var i=0; i < resolution; i++){
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset] = resolution + i;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+2] = ((i+1) % resolution) + resolution;
            triangleIndices[triangleoffset+1] =2*resolution +1; 
            triangleoffset +=3;
            groupCount += 3;
        }

        scope.addGroup(groupOffset, groupCount-groupOffset, 1);
    }
}

CylinderBufferGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype);
CylinderBufferGeometry.prototype.constructor = CylinderBufferGeometry;

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x404040, 1);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    window.onresize = resize;

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 3, 3, 3 );

    // controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");
    var texture1 = loader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/hardwood2_diffuse.jpg");
    texture1.wrapS = texture1.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture1.repeat.set(2.0*Math.PI, 1.0);
    var texture2 = loader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif");
    texture2.wrapS = texture1.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture2.repeat.set(1.0, 1.0);
    
    // materials
    material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture1
        });
    material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture2
        });
    
    var geometry = new CylinderGeometry(1.0, 0.3, 0.5, 16, false);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material_1, material_2]);
    mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    
    // mesh
    scene.add( mesh );

    lastTime = Date.now();
}

function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```